# Can I boost Lucene query parser results based on expected data?

Tags: asp.net, lucene

I have a Lucene index where one of the indexed fields contains a string that identifies the type of content.

For simplicity, say this field is called `_type` and will only ever contain `typeone` or `typetwo`.

I am using Lucene query parser syntax to query this index. Say my query is:

```
(+fieldone:term^3.0 +classname:term^2.0)
```

Is it possible to extend this to boost any results that have `typeone` in their `_type` field, whilst still returning `typetwo` records (albeit with a lower relevancy score)?

**UPDATE**

I've found a syntax which works but it uses the wildcard 'all documents' syntax which I suspect is not efficient. Advice appreciated.

```
(+fieldone:term^3.0 +classname:term^2.0) +(*:* _type:typeone^1.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just Lucene syntax you can simply keep the _type boost as SHOULD in the following way:

```
+fieldone:term^3.0 +classname:term^2.0 (_type:typeone)^2
```

you don't need wildcards.

Another solution would be using eDismax query parser then you can use the **bq** or **bf**  parameter in order to boost a particular value for a field. You can use one of the following solutions:

**Solution 1**: you can boost your term in the following way:

```
defType=edismax&bq=_type:"typeone"^3
```

or

**Solution 2:** you can use a query function in the following way:

```
defType=edismax&bf=if(termfreq(_type,"typeone"),3,if(termfreq(_type,"typetwo"),2,1))
```

where the results having _type=typeone are boosted by 3, the ones having typetwo are boosted by 2, otherwise it will be 1. You can modify that query according your needs.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I'm not familiar with eDismax but a quick test would suggest this is not compatible with what I'm doing. I need a syntax parsable by Luke http://www.getopt.org/luke/ - but thanks anyway.

Comment: In that case you can simply keep the _type boost as should in the following way  +fieldone:term^3.0 +classname:term^2.0 (_type:typeone)^2, you don't need the wildcards.

Comment: So you can! I only have very basic understanding of this syntax. Excellent news. Thank you. If you add this as an answer I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: Glad this solves your issue. I just edited my previous answer adding the solution posted in the comment. Cheers.